# limit no codeigniter

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, jquery-datatables

Eu tenho um código que pega os dados do banco de dados e mostra eles em uma tabela. Preciso com que ele apareça apenas os dois primeiros registros. Para isso coloquei um limit no meu código. Só que ele não está limitando, e sim pegando o total e diminuindo pelo número.

EX: `$this->db->limit(0,5);`
Nesse código ele pegaria o número total de registros menos o 5 que está no código e mostraria o que restou. Preciso que ele pegue o total e mostre apenas 2 desses registros.

MODEL:

```
public function getDoisLaudos($vei, $est, $urb, $rur, $aca) {
    $this->datatables->select('ls.la_id, ls.la_tipo, ls.la_data, usu.usr_nome, disp.dsp_nome, ls.la_densidade, ls.la_nivel, ls.la_zona, ls.la_status');
            $this->datatables->from('ls');
            $this->datatables->join('usu', 'ls.usr_id = usu.usr_id');
            $this->datatables->join('disp', 'ls.dsp_id = disp.dsp_id');
            $this->datatables->join('empresa', 'empresa.emp_id = usu.emp_id');
            $this->datatables->where('usu.emp_id = ' . $this->session->userdata('emp_id') . ' AND usu.usr_nivel<>0');
            $this->db->limit(0,5);

            $this->datatables->unset_column('ls.la_id');
            $this->datatables->unset_column('ls.la_status');
            $this->datatables->add_column('Ações', '$1', 'get_buttons_laudos(ls.la_id, ls.la_status, ls.la_tipo,' . $aca . ')');
            $this->datatables->edit_column('ls.la_tipo', '$1', 'trataLauTipo(ls.la_tipo,' . $vei . ',' . $est . ')');
            $this->datatables->edit_column('ls.la_data', '$1', 'tratarDataHora(ls.la_data)');
            $this->datatables->edit_column('ls.la_zona', '$1', 'trataLauPerimetro(ls.la_zona,' . $urb . ',' . $rur . ')');
            $this->datatables->edit_column('ls.la_status', '$1', 'trataLauStatus(ls.la_status)');
            return $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function generateTable() {
            echo $this->ML->getDoisLaudos($this->lang->line("con_laudo_tip_insp_v"), $this->lang->line("con_laudo_tip_insp_e"), $this->lang->line("con_laudo_per_insp_u"), $this->lang->line("con_laudo_per_insp_r"), $this->lang->line("con_laudo_acoes_insp"));

    }
```

Comment: Vejo que esta usando a library https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables . Essa library eu uso para uma tabela quando se tem muitos dados e precisa de ajax que dai irá fazer esse limit por "traz dos panos". Eu aconselharia mudar um pouco as coisas, se vc só quer mesmo mostrar dois registros, então imagino que não precisa trazer esses dois dados por ajax, então pq não usar fazer do modo normal? Mas dai teria um pouco de mudanças.

Answer (score 0):

Inverta a ordem dos argumentos do limit: `$this->db->limit(5,0)`, pois isso gerará uma expressão `LIMIT 0,5`, onde 0 é o offset e 5 é o count. Da forma como está fazendo, ele está dando um offset de 5 e limitando a 0, o que faz retornar todo o resto.

Na documentação oficial você pode entender melhor esses detalhes: [Active Record : CodeIgniter User Guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) .

Abraço.

Comment: Realizei a alteração, mas ela retornou todos os registros do banco da maneira que você me enviou. Preciso que ele só apareça dois de todos os registros. Desde já agradeço. Abraço

Answer (score 0):

Deve-se usar apenas o primeiro parâmetro do método `limit()`, que é a quantidade, porque o segundo parâmetro é o *offset* (deslocamento):

```
$this->db->limit(2);
```

Porém, nem todos os bancos possuem uma implementação desta funcionalidade, como o Microsoft SQL Server 2000. Se você estiver utilizando um banco desses, não é gerado nenhum erro, mas também a cláusula não é executada. Isto faz você ficar achando que não programou certo.

Answer (score 0):

Se for no Mysql você pode usar assim:

```
$this->db->limit(0, 5);   // Produz: LIMIT 5, 0 (no MySQL. Outros bancos de dados possuem uma sintaxe ligeiramente diferente)
```

Desse jeito funciona para todos os bancos:

```
$this->db->limit(5);   // produz: LIMIT 5
```

[Consulte a Documentação do Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)